# What is /proc/filesystems supposed to be and why is it different from /lib/modules/linux_ver/kernel/fs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, kernel-modules, procfs

The very little documentation about `/proc/filesystems` says it is a "list of supported file systems". I see a lot of file system modules in `/lib/modules/linux_ver/kernel/fs`, most of which do not appear in `/proc/filesystems`, nevertheless mount appears to have no problem using those file system modules.

So what is the use of `/proc/filesystems`? And why is it different from the list of filesystem modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an available module for the file system you want to mount but it's not yet loaded and hence isn't yet shown in `/proc/filesystems`, then it will be loaded on-demand which it why you don't have any problem mounting.

After having mounted such a file system, then that file system type should have appeared in `/proc/filesystems`.

Hence it is a "list of supported file systems for which the driver is already loaded"; additional file systems may be added by loading the appropriate module.

Comment: confirmed by modprobing more fs modules, thanks!